# Calculating APY formula in C

Tags: c

Im trying to calculate an APY formula and when compiled it shoots out 0.0000 when there is an input. I don't know if there is an error in my code or in the way im compiled it, but the answer should be output to .0618 when .06 in input.

```
    /* "APY.c", APY Calculator
Name: Tanner Oelke
Date: 2015/09/01
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    //define variables
    double apy, nominalIntRate;

    //ask user for interest rate
    printf("Please enter nominal interest rate:");
    scanf("%lf", &nominalIntRate);

    //calculates apy
    apy = exp(nominalIntRate) -1;

    printf("The APY is: %.4lf\n", &nominalIntRate);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You compute `apy`, but print `nominalIntRate`.

Comment: @ScottHunter Been a while since I've done C, but isn't he printing the *address* of `nominalIntRate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a good framework but there are two flaws in your program. First of all, `scanf` takes a pointer to the variables it reads into so as to be able to alter their values, but `printf` does not require a pointer, just the value. Secondly, you should print the value you want, not some other value. The line

```
printf("The APY is: %.4lf\n", &nominalIntRate);
```

should read

```
printf("The APY is: %.4lf\n", apy);
```

Comment: ahhh, I thought i had a simple mistake somewhere! This is still one of my first programs, thank you very much!!